# Advanced label expression in ArcMap to exclude part of a string

Tags: arcmap, labeling, python-parser

How do I write an advanced labeling expressions to only show a part of a string?

I want my data that looks like this EVA007 only to show the 007 part.

Comment: What's the rule for your labeling? Is it cutting the frist three letters? Or cutting everything except numbers?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to cut the first three letters, you can use the following Python expression (set option "advanced" expression):

```
def FindLabel([NAME]):
  return [NAME][3:]
```

If you want to keep the last three characters (numbers in your case) instead of cutting the first three, change `[3:]` to `[:-3]`.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the VB script, the solution could be

```
Right([FIELDNAME], 3)
```

or

```
Replace([FIELDNAME], "EVA", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, if you wanted to remove the alphabets and show the ending numbers only:

```
import re
def FindLabel ( [FIELDNAME] ):
  p = re.search('[0-9]+', [FIELDNAME])
  if p is None:  
   return [FIELDNAME]
  else:  
   return p.group(0).replace('(','')
```