# Writing advanced label expression for ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, python-parser, labeling

I have a label that I need to format using label expression. The label looks like this:

> EVA09C

and I want the outcome to be this:

> EA09C

Can I tell the label expression to skip the V in there?

Comment: Are your labels all formatted the same way? Is the letter you want to omit always in the second position?

Comment: Unless I am going blind what "H" are you talking about, did you mean "V" as that is the only missing character in your desired output?

Comment: Answers to this question and your very similar earlier one at https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/291478/115 appear to be pure Python (or pure VBscript) so will have already been answered multiple times at [so] if you do not find answers here before posting them.  Only the way the Python Parser uses field name/value variables is different.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It is Always want to omit the second positions as lambertj says. And sorry Hronbydd I meant "V". Thanks for pointing that out PolyGeo. Sorry for unclear question.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

One option would be this (replace FIELDNAME with the actual name of your field):

```
Replace([FIELDNAME], "V", "")
```

or

```
[FIELDNAME].replace("V", "")
```

if you prefer the Python parser.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that removes the second character:

```
def FindLabel ( [FIELDNAME] ):
    s= [FIELDNAME]
    return  s[0]+s[2:]
```

[Python parser]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```
Left([FIELDNAME], 1) & Right([FIELDNAME], 4)
```